# Jasmine how to check if two objects are exactly the same?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

This is very basic problem but at the same time in multiple posts it has no solution. How to check if two objects are exactly the same.
I tried that:

```
let objectToCopy = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
let copy = {};        
Helper.deepCopy(copy, objectToCopy, true, null);
expect(objectToCopy).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(copy));//it passes even if copy does contain only some of the objectToCopy fields
```

However it is very lenient, how to test if the objects are equal, it means all their properties are equal?

Of course I tried:

```
expect(objectToCopy).toEqual(copy);
```

it does not compile:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`objectContaining()` is not used for exact matches but for asymmetrical ones.

Simply use: `expect(objectToCopy).toEqual(copy)`

Comment: This is the first thing I tried and it does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is:

`expect(copy).toEqual(objectToCopy);`

or

`expect<any>(objectToCopy).toEqual(copy);`

The original way didn't work because TypeScript has parametrized the method with the type of the given argument.